# Valor de columnas por fila de excel java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

estoy intentando obtener los valores de las celdas que forman una fila de un documento excel.
La cuestión es que los recupero todos seguidos pero me gustaría recuperar el valor de una celda en concreto.

Pongo aquí el código.
Gracias de antemano.

```
public void leerExcel(File excel){

    List cellData = new ArrayList();

    try{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet hoja = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIterator = hoja.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = row.cellIterator();
            List cellTemp = new ArrayList();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                    cellTemp.add(cell);
                }
            cellData.add(cellTemp);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    obtenerDatos(cellData);
}

public void obtenerDatos (List cellList){

    for(int i=0; i<cellList.size(); i++){
        List listado = (List) cellList.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<listado.size();j++){
            XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) listado.get(j);
            String valor = celdas.toString();
            System.out.print(valor+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, no me queda claro que quieres conseguir, imprimir solamente una celda? Devolver su valor? Separar los datos?

Comment: Buenas tardes, lo que quería hacer una vez leída obtener por separado los valores de cada celda.

Answer (score 0):

Estás obteniendo el valor de cada celda dentro del método `obtenerDatos`, el problema es que lo estás imprimiendo todos en forma concatenada. Lo que podrías hacer para obtenerlos separados es lo siguiente:

```
public List obtenerDatos(List cellList){

    List results = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0; i<cellList.size(); i++){
        List listado = (List) cellList.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<listado.size();j++){
            XSSFCell celdas = (XSSFCell) listado.get(j);
            String valor = celdas.toString();
            results.add(valor);
        }
   }

   return results;
}
```

De esta forma, tu método retornaría una lista con un elemento por cada celda que exista.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! lo pongo en práctica ya!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor de una celda específica en tu código, primero necesitas determinar la fila y columna de la celda que deseas. Una vez que tienes esta información, puedes utilizar el método "getCell" de la clase "XSSFRow" para obtener un objeto de la clase "XSSFCell" que representa la celda específica. A continuación, puedes utilizar el método "getStringCellValue" para obtener el valor de la celda como una cadena.

Aquí te muestro como se podria hacer para obtener el valor de la celda en la fila 2, columna 3:

```
XSSFRow row = hoja.getRow(1);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);
String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
System.out.println("Valor de la celda: " + cellValue);
```

Donde el valor de '1' es la fila y el valor de '2' es la columna en la celda, estos valores pueden variar segun tu necesidad.

Además, si quieres recorrer un rango especifico de celdas, puedes utilizar el método "getCellRange" y especificar el rango de celdas que deseas recorrer, por ejemplo:

```
CellRangeAddress range = new CellRangeAddress(1, 3, 1, 4);
Iterator<Row> rows = hoja.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
    while (cells.hasNext()) {
        XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
        if (range.isInRange(cell.getRowIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex())) {
            String valor = cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.print(valor + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

De esta manera estarías recorriendo solo las celdas dentro del rango especificado, espero te sea de ayuda, cualquier otra duda no dudes en preguntar.